# ggplot2 geom_boxplot in polar coordinates: 0-180 direction not vertical

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display a boxplot of values against orientation sectors in
polar coordinates but the resultant 0 - 180 axis is not in the vertical
direction. Why?
This is what I do:

```
#Make concentration data (lognormal)
conc <- rnorm(1000,mean=20,sd=5)
conc <- 10^conc
hist(conc)
hist(log10(conc))
#Elements
element <- sample(x=LETTERS[1:3],size=1000,replace=TRUE)
table(element)
#Make distance data
dist <- runif(1000,0.1,50)
#Make orientation data
ang <- rnorm(1000,mean=180,sd=50)
ang[ang<0] <- 0
ang[ang>360] <- 360
hist(ang)
summary(ang)
#Orientation in sectors
angc <- cut(ang,breaks=seq(0,360,by=22.5))
levels(angc) <- as.character(c(0,45,45,90,90,135,135,180,180,225,225,270,270,315,315,0))
#Organize in df
df <-data.frame(ID=as.character(1:1000), 
                element=element,
                distance=dist,
                angle=ang, sector=angc,
                concentration=conc)
head(df)
#plot
p <- ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=sector,y=concentration)) +
  scale_y_log10()
p
p + coord_polar() 
p + coord_polar() + facet_wrap(~element)
```

Added after answer by shadow:
If I define the following intervals:

```
angc <- cut(ang,breaks=seq(0,360,by=22.5))
angc3 <- angc
levels(angc3) <- c("(338,22.5]", 
                   rep("(22.5,67.5]",2), rep("(67.5,90]",2), rep("(90,135]",2),
                   rep("(135,180]",2),   rep("(180,225]",2), rep("(225,270]",2),
                   rep("(270,338]",2),
                   "(338,22.5]")
df <-data.frame(ID=as.character(1:1000), 
                element=element,
                distance=dist,
                angle=ang, 
                sector=angc3,
                concentration=conc)
p <- ggplot(data=df) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=sector,y=concentration)) +
    scale_y_log10()
```

p + coord_polar()

Now the interval 338,22.5 has 0 at the center but it is still not in vertical position. I guess I do not understand when you say: "it normally starts at the top and then distributes sectors equally". The (338,22.5] should be at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the function `coord_polar` with a discrete x-axis, it normally starts at the top and then distributes sectors equally. The breaks are then in the middle of the sectors and don't start at the top. In your case, you know that you will have 8 breaks, so you can just shift the starting point by `pi/8` (start is measured in radians)

```
p + coord_polar(start=-pi/8)
```

Comment: While your answer works perfectly well, I would like something more transparent for the user. I was re-leveling the factor precisely to get an intervals such that from 338 to 22.5 with 0 at the center.  Is there a way I can define the levels to this type of intervals and avoid having to shift the origin of the graphic?